# Why sometime adding conditions to query accelerate it in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, generated by Django ORM - `core_instauser` and `core_instauser_followers`. Please see below for the CREATE TABLE statements

Query for getting followers few accounts and ordering by some column (counts_followed_by) taking more then 30 seconds:

```
# SELECT
#   T3."id"
# FROM "core_instauser_followers"
#   INNER JOIN "core_instauser" T3 ON ("core_instauser_followers"."to_instauser_id" = T3."id")
# WHERE "core_instauser_followers"."from_instauser_id" IN (14275, 30533081)
# ORDER BY T3."counts_followed_by" DESC
# LIMIT 10;
   id   
--------
  23358
  17461
  34360
  34201
  30624
  12475
 306799
  19215
  21042
  27073
(10 rows)

Time: 32850.160 ms
```

But if add conditions, not changing result, query take only 0.3 seconds - faster in 100:

```
# SELECT
#   T3."id"
# FROM "core_instauser_followers"
#   INNER JOIN "core_instauser" T3 ON ("core_instauser_followers"."to_instauser_id" = T3."id")
# WHERE ("core_instauser_followers"."from_instauser_id" IN (14275, 30533081) AND T3."count_media" > 0 AND
#        T3."counts_follows" > -1 AND T3."counts_followed_by" > -1)
# ORDER BY T3."counts_followed_by" DESC
# LIMIT 10;
   id   
--------
  23358
  17461
  34360
  34201
  30624
  12475
 306799
  19215
  21042
  27073
(10 rows)

Time: 295.934 ms
```

All columns in tables have indexes.

Why is this happening?

## UPD

SQL for creating tables:

```
-- core_instauser

CREATE TABLE core_instauser (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    uid character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    username character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    full_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    profile_picture character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    counts_followed_by integer,
    counts_follows integer,
    count_media integer,
    owner_id integer,
    hidden boolean NOT NULL,
    loaded boolean NOT NULL,
    update_time timestamp with time zone,
    has_avatar boolean,
    follow_rate double precision,
    deleted boolean NOT NULL,
    bio text NOT NULL,
    count_loaded_followers integer NOT NULL,
    has_bio boolean,
    has_full_name boolean,
    has_website boolean,
    website text NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE core_instauser_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE ONLY core_instauser ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('core_instauser_id_seq'::regclass);

ALTER TABLE ONLY core_instauser
    ADD CONSTRAINT core_instauser_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY core_instauser
    ADD CONSTRAINT core_instauser_uid_key UNIQUE (uid);

CREATE INDEX core_instauser_count_media_480f209b0ba2dbd4_uniq ON core_instauser USING btree (count_media);
CREATE INDEX core_instauser_counts_followed_by_33a853f6d98098dc_uniq ON core_instauser USING btree (counts_followed_by);
CREATE INDEX core_instauser_counts_follows_66136283704427b2_uniq ON core_instauser USING btree (counts_follows);

-- core_instauser_followers

CREATE TABLE core_instauser_followers (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    from_instauser_id integer NOT NULL,
    to_instauser_id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE core_instauser_followers_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE ONLY core_instauser_followers ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('core_instauser_followers_id_seq'::regclass);

ALTER TABLE ONLY core_instauser_followers
    ADD CONSTRAINT core_instauser_followers_from_instauser_id_to_instauser_id_key UNIQUE (from_instauser_id, to_instauser_id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY core_instauser_followers
    ADD CONSTRAINT core_instauser_followers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE INDEX core_instauser_followers_f865d5f5 ON core_instauser_followers USING btree (from_instauser_id);
CREATE INDEX core_instauser_followers_f9b32b2c ON core_instauser_followers USING btree (to_instauser_id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY core_instauser_followers
    ADD CONSTRAINT core_in_from_instauser_id_2ac1cc9fc9c44a79_fk_core_instauser_id FOREIGN KEY (from_instauser_id) REFERENCES core_instauser(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

ALTER TABLE ONLY core_instauser_followers
    ADD CONSTRAINT core_inst_to_instauser_id_4236828dfe87cfb8_fk_core_instauser_id FOREIGN KEY (to_instauser_id) REFERENCES core_instauser(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Explains of queries:

first slow query without additional conditions

```
# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
#   T3."id"
# FROM "core_instauser_followers"
#   INNER JOIN "core_instauser" T3 ON ("core_instauser_followers"."to_instauser_id" = T3."id")
# WHERE "core_instauser_followers"."from_instauser_id" IN (14275, 30533081)
# ORDER BY T3."counts_followed_by" DESC
# LIMIT 10;

 Limit  (cost=1.13..32396.65 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=37561.457..37683.384 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..48956112.71 rows=15112 width=8) (actual time=37561.455..37683.369 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using core_instauser_counts_followed_by_33a853f6d98098dc_uniq on core_instauser t3  (cost=0.56..4942183.77 rows=31451512 width=8) (actual time=0.066..4153.129 rows=4492685 loops=1)
         ->  Index Only Scan using core_instauser_followers_from_instauser_id_to_instauser_id_key on core_instauser_followers  (cost=0.57..1.39 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=4492685)
               Index Cond: ((from_instauser_id = ANY ('{14275,30533081}'::integer[])) AND (to_instauser_id = t3.id))
               Heap Fetches: 10
 Total runtime: 37683.475 ms
(7 rows)
```

fast query with addional conditions

```
# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
#   T3."id"
# FROM "core_instauser_followers"
#   INNER JOIN "core_instauser" T3 ON ("core_instauser_followers"."to_instauser_id" = T3."id")
# WHERE ("core_instauser_followers"."from_instauser_id" IN (14275, 30533081) AND T3."count_media" > -1 AND
#        T3."counts_follows" > -1 AND T3."counts_followed_by" > -1)
# ORDER BY T3."counts_followed_by" DESC
# LIMIT 10;

 Limit  (cost=1.13..36969.96 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=24.635..222.119 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..35453106.76 rows=9590 width=8) (actual time=24.633..222.100 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using core_instauser_counts_followed_by_33a853f6d98098dc_uniq on core_instauser t3  (cost=0.56..5029740.19 rows=19958436 width=8) (actual time=0.037..60.866 rows=13387 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (counts_followed_by > (-1))
               Filter: ((count_media > (-1)) AND (counts_follows > (-1)))
         ->  Index Only Scan using core_instauser_followers_from_instauser_id_to_instauser_id_key on core_instauser_followers  (cost=0.57..1.51 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=13387)
               Index Cond: ((from_instauser_id = ANY ('{14275,30533081}'::integer[])) AND (to_instauser_id = t3.id))
               Heap Fetches: 10
 Total runtime: 222.208 ms
(9 rows)
```

## UPD 2

All filtered columns in second query (count_media, counts_follows, counts_followed_by) have values more or equal 0, so new conditions must not affect on finally result

```
# SELECT count(*)
  FROM core_instauser
  WHERE counts_followed_by < 0 OR count_media < 0 OR counts_follows < 0;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)

Time: 5.551 ms
```

Comment: Check the execution plans

Comment: Are your tables VACUUM ANALYZEd ?

Comment: @SR_ database restore from dump and probably not needed for VACUUM ANALYZEd

Answer (score 1):

When you added where predicate, you told optimizer that you are interested only in particular rows (core_instauser).

The Old query had to get a match for every row in core_instauser. For every rows=4492685 found it had to check the other table for a match.

The New query restricts core_instauser table to get only rows=13387 and it had to search other table only 13387 times.

When adding where predicate you will get the same amount of rows or less than actual table got.

Now to your question why different query gets the same result. 
In your case, it just happened that only those rows in core_instauser table have a match with core_instauser_followers. The answer might be different.

We can compare it with two bags of balls with numbers on them. 
One bag has 1,2 and 3. 
The other bag has 1 and 2.

Now you JOIN bags to get a match.

```
Select * from bag1 join bag2 on (number) will join two rows: 1 and 2.
```

Now you restrict bag1 to get all balls that are less than 3:

```
select * from bag1 join bag2 where bag1.number < 3.
The result will not change.
```